# I tried to use wireguard docker image,but I failed

Tags: compiling, docker, make

I deleted all the datas in VPS,and reinstall a new Centos 7
and I downloaded the lastest stable kernel source code 4.20 and extracted it to the source directory which is /usr/src,then I builded it.the kernel and modoules were sucessfully builded , however the wireguard docker image doesn't work

```
$ docker run --rm -it 
--name wireguard 
-v /etc/wireguard:/etc/wireguard 
-v /lib/modules:/lib/modules 
-v /usr/src:/usr/src:ro 
r.j3ss.co/wireguard:install
Unable to find image 'r.j3ss.co/wireguard:install' locally
install: Pulling from wireguard
cd784148e348: Pull complete
74376a61d579: Pull complete
dd348312c1df: Pull complete
bc712e2ba41a: Pull complete
Digest: 
sha256:375417a542a244537a92b60a9053ec5722c507dc38616b8f01c4e8333c56efa1
Status: Downloaded newer image for r.j3ss.co/wireguard:install
Building the wireguard kernel module...
CC [M] /wireguard/src/main.o
/bin/sh: scripts/basic/fixdep: not found
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:292: /wireguard/src/main.o] Error 127
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1563: module/wireguard/src] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:36: module] Error 2

$uname -r
4.20.3
```

any idea?what wrong I have done?

Comment: Try to build image only without your local mount points.

Comment: no way,it doesn't work as well